# Good way to do simple moving animation?

Tags: java

```
// The "Animation" class.
import java.awt.*;
import hsa.Console;

public class Animation
{
    static Console c;           // The output console


    public static void main (String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        c = new Console ();


        for (int index = 0 ; index < 300 ; index += 10)
        {



            // This is the night sky     
            c.setColor (Color.black);
            c.fillRect (0, 0, 1500, 700);
            c.drawRect (0, 0, 1500, 700);

            // This is the moon 
            c.setColor (Color.white);
            c.fillOval (550, 10, 80, 90);

            // These are the stars in the background 
            c.setColor (Color.yellow);
            c.fillStar (50, 70, 20, 20);
            c.fillStar (90, 100, 20, 20);
            c.fillStar (130, 70, 20, 20);
            c.fillStar (210, 70, 20, 20);
            c.fillStar (290, 70, 20, 20);
            c.fillStar (370, 70, 20, 20);
            c.fillStar (450, 70, 20, 20);
            c.fillStar (170, 100, 20, 20);
            c.fillStar (250, 100, 20, 20);
            c.fillStar (330, 100, 20, 20);
            c.fillStar (410, 100, 20, 20);

            // This is the shooting star 
            c.fillStar (index, index, index + 20, index + 10);

            Thread.sleep (1400);




        }

        // Place your program here.  'c' is the output console
    } // main method
} // Animation class
```

We are working on our summatives in computer science and the task is to use our knowledge in Java to construct a program which can run a simple animation. This is the code i got so far the problem is that the shooting star keeps getting bigger and bigger but I would like it to stay as 1 size, do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is because you are using the `index` in your `width` and `height` parameters. I also assume the Javadoc for this API is [here](http://www.brentwoodhigh.com/apcs/holt/hsa-javadoc/Console.html). If so, I'd suggest something like:

```
c.fillStar(index, index, 20, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
        c.fillStar (index, index, index + 20, index + 10);
```

by

```
        c.fillStar (index, index,  20,  10);
```